# iOS Region Monitoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I'm creating an app that uses Core Location. I read the developer guide for Core Location but I still have a doubt. **I didn't understand if I need to use the function `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` for monitoring only the regions enter and exit events.** I implemented the delegated methods `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion`. What I did understand is that if I want to be updated all the time I need to implement the delegated method `didUpdateLocations` and call the function `startUpdatingLocation`.

So the question is: do I have to call `startUpdatingLocation` method for monitoring regions only in foreground and background modes? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably only need to set:

- startMonitoringForRegion:
- stopMonitoringForRegion:

Then once just implement the delegate methods you entered.